# Shell Scripting: Using grep and tr in the shebang

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, tr

I have this script on my system:

```
#! /bin/grep cat

caterpillar
cat
lol
morecat
```

When I run it, I get the output as expected,

```
#! /bin/grep cat
caterpillar
cat
morecat
```

But, if I use tr instead, with the script

```
#! /usr/bin/tr 'a' 'e'

caterpillar
cat
lol
morecat
```

I expect to get

```
#! /usr/bin/tr 'a' 'e'

ceterpiller
cet
lol
morecet
```

But instead nothing is printed, and if I manually type `cat`, I get `c/t`.  How can the script be changed to behave like the first?

Comment: Because `grep` takes a file argument, but `tr` does not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shebang line only supports a single argument. Spaces are included literally and there is no quoting. So the command you're running there is equivalent to this from a shell:

```
tr "'a' 'e'"
```

If you run that you'll see that `tr` complains about the lack of a second argument. So why does your script not complain? Well that's the second problem. shebang `cat` or `grep` works because `cat` and `grep` takes name of an input file as an argument, and the shebang adds the script's name to the argument list. (That's required for the basic case of a `#!/bin/sh` script to be executed as `/bin/sh scriptname`)

You are therefore running

```
tr "'a' 'e'" yourscriptname
```

which gives `tr` the 2 arguments it needs, and it then reads from stdin, translating from a set of characters you didn't intend to another set of characters you didn't intend.

If the shebang line had a fully functional shell parser, you could use

```
#!/usr/bin/tr 'a' 'e' <
```

And the filename added to the end would become the input. But shebang is just a simple thing in the kernel, not so featureful.

Comment: Thanks!  That would also explain why "#! /bin/bash cat" is printed as well.